# Application cant access file on startup

Tags: delphi, startup, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I'm doing an application(XE6 , Firemonkey)  to synchronize files between a shared folder and a computer/s. This application checks every x hours if there are new files to be synchronized, and it starts on windows start-up.

I can do everything, my application starts on start-up, and it does the synchronization, as long as i'm the one starting it. Whem the application auto starts on start up it gives me an exception "EINOUTERROR" - File Access Denied.
On starting the application reads a small .txt file to set up it self (shared folder location, rate of synchronization etc), my guess is that since its the windows starting the app runs it without privileges to read the .txt, but even after changing the .txt permissions to full control on everyone it gives the same error.

File open code:

```
 AssignFile(myFile,'Dados.txt');

    if FileExists('Dados.txt') then
        Append(myFile)
    else
        Rewrite(myFile);

   FileMode := fmOpenRead;
   Reset(myFile);
```

Code of placing the app on startup programs :

```
procedure TSyncM.RunOnStartup(const sCmdLine: string; bRunOnce: boolean; Remove: Boolean) ;
var   sKey: string;
Section: string;
const   ApplicationTitle = 'GEN4Sync';
begin
      if (bRunOnce) then
          sKey := 'Once'
      else
          sKey := '';
          Section := 'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run' + sKey + #0;
            with TRegIniFile.Create('') do
                try
                 RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
                 if Remove then
                  DeleteKey(Section, ApplicationTitle)
                 else
                  WriteString(Section, ApplicationTitle, sCmdLine) ;
                finally
                  Free;
                end;
end;
```

If i comment the piece of code that calls the reading of that .txt my app starts and executes well, but i don't want to set it up everytime.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the issue is related to your use of relative paths. You have written the code under the assumption that the working directory is the same directory as contains the executable. That is not necessarily so.

When you start the application by double clicking on the executable file, for instance, the shell ensures that the initial working directory is the directory containing the executable file. However, when Windows starts your program at startup I suspect that the working directory is the system directory. And of course your file is not found there, and you don't have rights to write there.

Instead of using relative paths, use the full path to the file.

```
FileName := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Dados.txt';
```

Or perhaps

```
FileName := TPath.Combine(ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)), 'Dados.txt');
```

Note that this does also assume that your executable file is located in a folder which you can write to. That is often not the case so you may need to find a different location.

I do have to comment that I find it somewhat incongruous that you are mixing the very modern (FireMonkey) with the ancient (Pascal I/O). Perhaps it is time to move to a more modern I/O technique.

Comment: Yes, using the full path solved the issue. Thanks.
By saying a more modern I/O technique, what do you suggest? ( not asking for the code, just a heads up for me to search and learn :) )
I am pretty newbie to Firemonkey and Delphi, and that ancient Pascal I/O was the first thing that appeared on google.

Comment: What are the contents of the file?

Comment: Plain text. 
Well, i have  set of shared folders, and i need to ensure that some computers keep an up to date copy of those shared folders. I have a class that stores that information, at first i wanted to serialize that class and store it on a file, just like in java, but i found it difficult in delphi. And since this is a small project of mine, i tried to keep it simple and small time consuming. So i wrote a procedure that reads the class and writes it on a txt, then i interpret it on app start up.

Comment: You could use SuperObject or some other JSON based serialization library for that.  That would serialize (and deserialze) simple record types with no effort required from you.  As for reading and writing text files, presumably that is line based. So a stream reader/writer is the easy way to move to modern I/O and keep the same style of code that you used with Pascal I/O.

Comment: You maybe don't know Windows can do directly what you're trying to code...  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/how-to-keep-your-information-in-sync

Comment: I'm not trying to code, i coded already. And Yes if i knew that sooner, i wouldn't be "inventing the wheel" again, nevertheless its always nice to learn a few things . Thank you for the info.
@DavidHeffernan Yes, JSON based serialization will be very useful for me in the future. I've changed by app to stream reader/writer as u sugested. Thanks!